# Combinatorics of arithmetic progressions in $~\{1,2,\cdots, 9\}~$

Tags: combinatorics

This problem is from a high-school competition (found online but I can't remember where):

Given the set A $=~\{1,2,\cdots, 9\}~$ and B, C disjoint sets such that B $∪$ C $=$ A.

Then B or C contains $~3~$ numbers $~x,~y,~z~$ such that $~2y = x+z~$.

As I'm not experienced in combinatorial arguments, my question is:

Is there a way to prove it without explicitly examining all the possible cases?

What I find interesting is the structure of this problem:

an initial configuration where a property holds, a transformation applied, and a  resulting configuration where the property continues to hold.

So if there are similar combinatorial problems and methods to attack them, please offer your suggestions and guidance.

Comment: Another way of putting is, if all the numbers from $1$ to $9$ are colored either red or blue, then there will be a three-term arithmetic progression, all of who elements are colored the same color.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem  The proof in Khinchin's "Three Pearls of Number Theory" mentioned in the wiki article is delightful.

Comment: @saulspatz  thank you, this is very much in the spirit i was looking for.